# trying to send httpRequest from server side in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am trying to make http request to server from my GWT Application

Below is the code i am using which works fine from Client Side ..

But I want to do this from Server side ..

If I can get some solution for that

```
     String url = "http://www.myserver.com/getData?type=3";
     RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

      try { 
      Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
      public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
   // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)
      }

    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
      // Process the response in response.getText()
   } else {
    // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
   }
 }
 });
 } catch (RequestException e) {
   // Couldn't connect to server
}
```

Reference: www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

Comment: you can use any rest client.. like apache-http for that

Answer (score 2):

com.google.gwt.http.**client**.RequestBuilder is meant to be used on the GWT client side.

For your server side code to make HTTP requests, I recommend using the [Apache HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).